# PayPal Integration with Android

Tags: android, paypal

I have seen some related questions but none focusing on the specific problem I have:

I'm using the PayPal MPL Library.

I build my PayPalPayment object, then create the activity for the checkout to occur. That runs fine. My problem is, on the ResultDelegate I need to call a function from my activity, that occurs after the payment and makes some changes (such as storing SharedPreferences, etc.).

So something like this:

```
public class ResultDelegate implements PayPalResultDelegate, Serializable {
    public void onPaymentSucceeded(String payKey, String paymentStatus) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS, You have successfully completed your transaction.");
        System.out.println("PayKey: "+payKey);
        System.out.println("PayStatus: "+paymentStatus);

        callMyCustomAfterPaymentFunction();
    }
    ...
}
```

Now the thing is, I tried to create a constructor for ResultDelegate that accepts my activity. My existing code is:

```
//On the activity class
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
        Button buy = (Button) findViewByID(R.id.buy_button);
        buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                new PurchaseTask(activity).execute();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PurchaseTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground()
    {
        ...
        PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
        CheckoutButton cb = pp.getCheckoutButton(...);
        cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                ResultDelegate delegate = new ResultDelegate(myActivity);
                Intent checkout = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(paument, activity, delegate);
                activity.StartActivity(checkoutIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}

//On the ResultDelegate class

public class ResultDelegate implements PayPalResultDelegate, Serializable {
    private Activity myActivity;

    public void onPaymentSucceeded(String payKey, String paymentStatus) {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS, You have successfully completed your transaction.");
        System.out.println("PayKey: "+payKey);
        System.out.println("PayStatus: "+paymentStatus);

        myActivity.performAfterPaymentOperations();
    }
    ...
}
```

So the goal is to call the activity function from the ResultDelegate. Or even simpler, just to be able to store some SharedPreference changes when the ResultDelegate onPaymentSucceeded() fires.

But I get a NotSerializableException mentioning that the my MyActivity field is not Serializable.

So, then I added the transient identifier to my activity field inside the ResultDelegate, but now I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: is your `Delegate` a sperate Thread? Please post a SSCCE. or post your `Activty` and `Delegate` code.

Comment: I assume so. The PayPal activity is called through an Intent. The ResultDelegate is a PayPal class subclassed to make a custom one, then used as a parameter when creating the PayPal activity. The subclassing of ResultDelegate allows you to place your own code in the onPaymentSucceeded() listener, which fires when the PayPalActivity completes a payment. However, I cannot access my activity from inside the ResultDelegate, which is crucial.

Code edited for better readability and details added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Paypal Mobile Chekout guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf)

Implementation provided on paypal website is different from yours. They are doing `startActivityForResult()` to start `PaypalActivity`.  and when in `onActivityResult()` method they are checking `statusCode` to check transaction status and act accordingly.

Follow that document for your implementation.

Here in your code, I donot find a point for using `AsyncTask`. Your `ResultDelegate` is `Serializable` where as `Activity` is not thats why it is throwing `NotSerializableException`.

**Edit:**

As you are developing for Google Android platform, then why not to use Google Checkout In-App?

**Edit:**

This method will be called when your `PaypalActivity` will finish. That activity will pass `resultCode` to this `onActivityResult` method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (resultCode) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        // The payment succeeded
        String payKey = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        // Tell the user their payment succeeded
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
        // The payment was canceled
        // Tell the user their payment was canceled
        break;
    case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
        // The payment failed -- we get the error from the EXTRA_ERROR_ID
        // and EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE
        String errorID = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
        String errorMessage = data
                .getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        // Tell the user their payment was failed.
    }
}
```

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Comment: Hello, I am developing for a country Google Play unfortunately does not support.

The startActivityForResult detail does seem to make sense. I will test it and reply soon.

Comment: okay, and please check edit for your `resultCode` variable question that you just asked in your comment before edit.

Comment: am also plan to integrate paypal in to android app i need some help.am using android paypal sdk and fallow the below link :            http://mayuran26.blogspot.in/2014/09/integrate-paypal-account-to-your.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create you custom listener something like this :

Create a custom listener :

```
  OnDoubleTap mListener;

    // Double tap custome listenre to edit photoes
    public interface OnDoubleTap {
        public void onEvent(Uri imgPath, int mPos);

    }

    public void setDoubleTapListener(OnDoubleTap eventListener) {
        mListener = eventListener;

    }
```

Now call this wherever you want like this :

```
mListener.onEvent(Uri, 1));
```

Now whenever you call this listener this will fire in your activity where you use this listener like this :

```
myCanvas.setDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTap() {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(Uri imgPath, int Pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "LISTENER WORKING !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Where myCanvas is object of class where you create you listener.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But the matter was, after all, the onActivityResult listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(price),getResources().getString(R.string.curruncy_code), getResources().getString(R.string.app_name),
                    PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateEventStep4.this, PaymentActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAYPAL_PAYMENT);
```

---

```
PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {

                    Log.e("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString());


                    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(confirm.toJSONObject().toString());

                    String paymentId=jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getString("id");
                    System.out.println("payment id:-=="+paymentId);

                    screenShotFile = takeScreenshot(frmTemplate);
                    uploadImage(myEvent.getEvent_id(),screenShotFile);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
                }
```